# No notifications (prevent device sleep?)

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-source

I have a huge problem with my application regarding notifications. I'm not using FCM, so my app is using foreground service for receiving them. Everything works, but if the device is not used for approximately 30-60 minutes, the device goes in some kind of sleep mode (?) and it's not receiving the notifications anymore. If I wait long enough, it will ring after 40 minutes, but that's a little bit too much.

- If I tap on the screen, it's getting the notification instantly
- charging the phone: also getting the notification instantly

I tried to play with the battery settings on the phone. Using "not optimize" for my app. Tried to set "not optimize" for every app. Disabled battery manager.. Tried with mobile network, tried with WiFi, tried with "screen always on", but no success.

The phone is using an AOSP based firmware (syberiaOS).

Is there any way to fix this? I heard that android changed something after nougat for better battery lifetime, but I don't care about the lifetime.

Thank you for reading, maybe someone could help.

Comment: I hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64870635/8851971) answers your question.

Comment: In my opinion (I've tried many different solutions) there's no way to prevent any service from being killed after a while. They do that, no matter if you want to optimize your app or not. Why can't you use FCM?

Comment: Try adding your app to the "allow-in-power-save" whitelist inside platform.xml at /frameworks/base/data/etc/